# Mercurial clone without history

Tags: mercurial, clone

I'm trying to download the source code for a large open source project, so I can look at it.

It says to do:

```
hg clone http://server/path
```

However, this is taking forever (I'm assuming because it's a large project). I don't really care about the changesets; I just want the head, and I'm not going to be committing anything.

Is there any way I can just that, without everything else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Often, when you just point your browser to the repository URL, you can grab a tarball of any revision you like, inluding head. This feature has to be enabled on the server side, though.

Comment: It wasn't enabled, but it led me down a path where I found their link.